# How to use search in MDX that returns matches from two keywords

Tags: mdx, pentaho, olap, olap-cube, mondrian

I am new to mdx.

Is there any way to search and return matches from two keywords using MDX like we use in MySQL using LIKE '%iphone' AND LIKE '%samsung'?

My MDXcode is:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Average Price]} ON COLUMNS,
Filter({[Product Names].MEMBERS},
[Product Name].CurrentMember.Name MATCHES '(?i)apple.*' or [Product Name].CurrentMember.Name MATCHES '(?i)screen.*') ON ROWS
FROM [Price History]
```

Here in my code, any search is satisfied, but I want both conditions to be satisfied.

Is there any way, please help?

Comment: From your question it looks like you just need to replace `or` with `and` in your `Filter` condition.

Answer (score 3):

`MDX` does not have the `LIKE` operator, but you can use the `InStr`function to check if the  check if the keywords are part of the name.

```
with member measures.iPhoneInName as
VBA!InStr([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name, "iPhone")

member measures.SamsungInName as
VBA!InStr([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name, "Samsung")

SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Average Price]} 
ON COLUMNS,
[Product Names].MEMBERS
HAVING 
   measures.iPhoneInName >= 1 
   OR 
   measures.SamsungInName >= 1 
ON ROWS 
FROM [Price History]
```

**EDIT:** 
If you want only those members whose name end with `iPhone` OR `Samsung`, then a small addition to the code:

```
(
    VBA!InStr([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name) + len("Samsung") + 1
    = LEN([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name)
    AND measures.SamsungInName >= 1
)
OR 
(
    VBA!InStr([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name) + len("iPhone") + 1
    = LEN([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name)
    AND measures.iPhoneInName >= 1
)
```

**Mondrian version**

```
    with member measures.iPhoneInName as
    VBA!InStr([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name, "iPhone")

    member measures.SamsungInName as
    VBA!InStr([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name, "Samsung")

    SELECT
    NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Average Price]} 
    ON COLUMNS,
    FILTER
    (
     [Product Names].MEMBERS,
        (
            VBA!InStr([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name) + len("Samsung") + 1
            = LEN([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name)
            AND measures.SamsungInName >= 1
        )
        OR 
        (
            VBA!InStr([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name) + len("iPhone") + 1
            = LEN([Product Name].CurrentMember.Name)
            AND measures.iPhoneInName >= 1
        )
    )
    ON ROWS 
    FROM [Price History]
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i tried your code but it says: MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Syntax error at line 11, column 1, token 'HAVING'

Comment: So `MONDRIAN`doesn't have `HAVING` clause! Wait, will add one more flavor.

Comment: @MidhunKrishna - added. Please check.

Comment: @SouravA- Hi, thanks for the edit, i tried again but it still says MondrianException: Mondrian Error:No function matches signature 'InStr(<String>)'. what is the error here, didn’t understand.